# Prime element definition and example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

From mathworld, prime element,***b*** is an element which is nonzero and non unit and if ***b*** divides a product in the ring, ***b*** divides one of the factors. My question is, $8$ divides $128$ in integer. But, $8$ divides both $8$ and $16$ which are the factors in $128$.So, is $8$ a prime element?

Comment: It works in this case, but does it work for numbers besides $128$?

Comment: Instead of "if it divides a product in the ring" you should say "if it divides ANY product in the ring". To show that $8$ is not prime, simply pick another product, for example $2 \cdot 4$ would suffice. Otherwise, using your argument, anything is prime: let's say $n$ is prime, because $n$ divides $2n$ and $n$ divides $n$, which is one of the factors. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TokenToucan So, I need to test for all other numbers as well?

Comment: Yes, the statement needs to hold for any product (as @Crostul wrote)

Answer (score 1):

It should be 'if $b$ divides a product, $b$ divides at least one of the factors'.
$8$ divides $16=4\times 4$ but does not divide $4$, so $8$ is not a prime.